# Householder transformation ; Eigenvalues are invariant under multiplication with hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I am reading about the householder reduction and I'm struggling at one point:

In the first step of the householder transformation we consider $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and a unitary matrix $Q_1:=I-2ww^H \in \mathbb{C}^{(n-1) \times (n-1)}$ with $P_1 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 &Q_1 \end{array}\right]$, such that
$P_1AP_1^H= \left[\begin{array}{cccc} * & ... & ... & *\\ * & ... & ... & *\\ 0 & * & ... & *\\ 0&*&*&* \end{array}\right]$.

Now the paper states that the multiplication with $P_1^H$ from the right makes sure that the eigenvalues of $A$ stay invariant under the multiplication. Why? Is it because of similarity of the matrices?

Comment: Yes, it's because of the similarity of the matrices